# How to fix "ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)" in mysql?

Tags: mysql, stored-functions, mysql-error-1241

i want to display details of drivers working in morning shift..

```
delimiter //
create function dShift(n int)
returns varchar(128)
deterministic
begin
return (select driver.driver_no,driver_name,licence_no,address,d_age,salary 
from driver,bus_driver as bd where bd.shift=n and bd.driver_no = 
driver.driver_no); 
end //
```

Comment: 'Statements that return a result set can be used within a stored procedure but not within a stored function' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html

Comment: You could concat all the columns to get round this if you are sure you only get one row returned by the select. Otherwise a function is not for you.

Answer (score 0):

In your function the return type is varchar `returns varchar(128)`. So it expects a single string as output. But you are returning 6 columns as output.

You can use the following way to get the list of columns as output:

```
delimiter //

CREATE FUNCTION dShift (n INT)
BEGIN
    SELECT driver.driver_no
        ,driver_name
        ,licence_no
        ,address
        ,d_age
        ,salary
    FROM driver
    JOIN bus_driver AS bd ON bd.driver_no = driver.driver_no
    WHERE bd.shift = n;
END //
```

Comment: I copied ur code and complied it..its giving an error  
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEGIN
    SELECT driver.driver_no
        ,driver_name
        ,licence_no
     ' at line 2

Comment: You are not allowed to return a result set from a function and this is missing returns and return stataments.